# Vim - change cursor in command line

Tags: vim

I'm trying to change cursor from block to vertical bar (I-beam) when entering Vim command line.

I was trying with this separate codes:

```
" with these two codes nothing happens
autocmd CmdlineEnter * let &t_SI
autocmd CmdlineEnter * execute &t_SI

" this last one  produce "E20: Mark not set" error
autocmd CmdlineEnter * execute '!echo -ne "' . &t_SI . '"'
```

Is something like that even possible or vim uses same cursor for cmd line like it uses in normal mode.
I've changed normal mode (&t_EI) to vertical bar and in that case cursor was vertical bar in cmd line.

Can cursor be changed in cmd line regardles of normal mode?
Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Vim [8.2.0258](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/4132eb505c506f7a0710b03a275d1c5a247e4196) or newer, the [`echoraw()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#echoraw%28%29) function can be used

```
autocmd CmdlineEnter * call echoraw(&t_SI)
autocmd CmdlineLeave * call echoraw(&t_EI)
```

Comment: This is better solution.

Comment: I used this answer's block cursor (`&t_EI`) for `autocmd VimEnter` because when I open vim from bash cursor is inherited from bash cursor shape and was always a "line" instead of "block" at the vim startup.

Answer (score 2):

I've found solution.
It turns out it's possible to change cursor when entering and leaving cmd line.

This code will change cursor to vertical bar when entering cmd line and revert it back to block when leaving cmd line.

```
" vim cursor escape codes for the terminal emulator
" INSERT (&t_SI)  - vertical bar (I-beam)
" REPLACE (&t_SR) - underscore
" VISUAL (&t_EI)  - block
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>[5 q"
let &t_SR = "\<Esc>[3 q"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>[1 q"

" set cursor to vertical bar when entering cmd line and
" revert cursor back to block when leaving cmd line
autocmd CmdlineEnter * execute 'silent !echo -ne "' . &t_SI . '"'
autocmd CmdlineLeave * execute 'silent !echo -ne "' . &t_EI . '"'
```